# How to place the elements one by one in grid system having opacity using bootstrap

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an angular application in that I have created the dashboard page In  dashboard page I have created the map using leaflet map ,and the data  which has to be placed right side of the map.

**Now I want to place the map first with of entire 12 grids and under the map I have to place the data of 3 tab links of 5 grids width using bootstrap**

I have tried but tab links are  coming after the map,but I want to show the tablinks on the map with right side with opacity using bootstrap.

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-12">

     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-12"  >

      <div id="map">

      </div>


    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-7"  >
</div>
<!--<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-5">-->
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-5" style="float: right; opacity: 0.4; z-index: 1;" >

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs border-0">
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <a href="#xx" class="nav-link border border-default border-bottom-0 active" data-toggle="tab"
          id="tabstyle" style=" font-size: 20px; color: red; font-weight: 500;">
          Drones</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#yy" class="nav-link border border-default border-bottom-0" data-toggle="tab" id="tabstyle"
          style=" font-size: 20px; color:  red;font-weight: 500;">Jammers</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#zz" class="nav-link border border-default border-bottom-0" data-toggle="tab" id="tabstyle"
          style=" font-size: 20px; color:  red;font-weight: 500;">Sensors</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
   
    <div class="tab-content">

      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="xx">

        <ul class="list-group card" id="dd">
         
        </ul>

      </div>

      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="yy">

        <ul class="list-group card" id="dd">
         
        </ul>

      </div>

      <div class="tab-pane fade " id="zz">

        <ul class="list-group card" id="dd">
          
        </ul>

      </div>
</div>
  </div>
 </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

**component.css**

```
#map{
  height: 550px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
margin-left: 5px;
position: relative;
}
```

I have tried many ways but I am not able to do that.

Can anyone help me regarding this

Comment: Bootstrap 3 or 4 ?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 4

Comment: I have tried many ways but not working can you please help me for layering of components using bootstrap for the above code

Comment: Just to be sure, you want that `tab-content` in the map on the right ?

Comment: yes,I want that tab content in right side of the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jus place your `tab-content` into your map as below with css:

```
.tab-content{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right:0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 200px;  /* ADDED for example */
  width: 200px;   /* ADDED for example */
  background: red; /* ADDED for example */
}
```

### DEMO

```css
#map{
  height: 550px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.tab-content{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right:0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 200px;  /* ADDED for example */
  width: 200px;   /* ADDED for example */
  background: red; /* ADDED for example */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-12">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-12"  >

          <div id="map">
            <div class="tab-content">

              <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="xx">

                <ul class="list-group card" id="dd">

                </ul>

              </div>

              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="yy">

                <ul class="list-group card" id="dd">

                </ul>

              </div>

              <div class="tab-pane fade " id="zz">

                <ul class="list-group card" id="dd">

                </ul>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-7"  >
</div>
<!--<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-5">-->
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-5" style="float: right; opacity: 0.4; z-index: 1;" >

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs border-0">
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <a href="#xx" class="nav-link border border-default border-bottom-0 active" data-toggle="tab"
          id="tabstyle" style=" font-size: 20px; color: red; font-weight: 500;">
          Drones</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#yy" class="nav-link border border-default border-bottom-0" data-toggle="tab" id="tabstyle"
          style=" font-size: 20px; color:  red;font-weight: 500;">Jammers</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#zz" class="nav-link border border-default border-bottom-0" data-toggle="tab" id="tabstyle"
          style=" font-size: 20px; color:  red;font-weight: 500;">Sensors</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks,but the tab content has to be in the top i.e with margin 0

Comment: Just change to:50% to 0 àd remove the transform.